# how to redirect to a specific page number in lazyloading datatable?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, lazy-loading

**hello i have a command link**

i want when i click the command it open the primefaces datatable in the second page or third .

is that possible? i tried changing the first and pagesize that are in the load() method but it didnt work for me

.
.
.

```
Offers = new LazyDataModel<Offer>() {  
     public List<Offer> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {  
    first=5;
      return EJB.getOffers(first,pagesize)
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set the page of the table to the first one

```
Offers.setFirst(site);
```

or Client side

```
widgetVar.getPaginator().setPage(pageindex);
```

Comment: I did not find setFirst on Offers these are the avalible setPageSize , setRowCount , setRowIndex ,setWrappedData